# Add a extra category attribute under general infomation tab

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category

I am trying adding a extra category attrbiute to **general infomation tab** i have tried adding that using the following code ,

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);


$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'nav_left',  array(
    'type'     => 'tinyint',
    'label'    => 'Show in left navgigation',
    'input'    => 'boolean',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'nav_left',
    '11'

//last Magento's attribute position in General tab is 10
);

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'nav_left');

$installer->run("
INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity_int')}`
(`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`)
    SELECT '{$entityTypeId}', '{$attributeId}', `entity_id`, '1'
        FROM `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity')}`;
");
```

This is just working fine but this is adding an additional information tab named `General` just to the right of `general infomation tab` i have tried adding it to first tab using `attributeGroupId` set to 4 but after testing it is just crashing the site.

Any idea how can i add that attribute to first tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'nav_left', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'Show in left navgigation',
    'input'    => 'boolean',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0
));
```

**EDIT**
`$installer` must be instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`.

Off topic a bit: I recommend adding this script in an update file of one of your modules instead of making an instance of `Mage::app()` and running it 'on the fly'. If you put it in an upgrade script it's portable to other instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after running this i am getting server error on the site.

Comment: what error are you getting? I edited the answer. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: the logs files contanis nothing the report file is saying. "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'wwwinsta_Joyevincent.catalog_category_entity_tinyint' doesn't exist"

Comment: Okzz this worked adding date attr in general info tab but i m trying adding a yes/No type attr any idea for that ?

Comment: The problem was the `type` of the attribute. It should be `int`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Marius Can I ask what exactly `'user_defined'=>false` means in this case? What would be the effect if we  replace `false` with `true`?

Comment: For products there is a restriction. You are not allowed to delete from the UI attributes that have 'user_defined' set to `false`. They are system attributes. For categories, since there is no UI for attributes, this shouldn't make a difference. But just to be sure, set the value to `true`

Comment: @Marius Thanks. I've also seen these parameters: `'backend'` and `'frontend'`. Are they also related to deleting attributes? Do you know what they exactly do? I couldn't find any info about it but these parameters are often used in tutorials about custom attributes.

Comment: I think you should better make a post with all the question you have about this. There is no point in discussing it over someone else's question because it's a bit off topic.

Answer (score 5):

I have managed it work in expected way like this.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'left_nav',  array(
    'group'    => 'General Information',
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'Show in left navigation',
    'input'    => 'select',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'
));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can custom yes/no attribute to category section using the following code.

```
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'featured_product', array(
'group'         => 'General Information',
'input'         => 'select',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Featured Product',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
```

));

Please refer my tutorial for step by step explanation and file structure.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/add-custom-attribute-dropdown-category-section-magento/