# How can set new label Icon for selected category in menu popup

Tags: magento-1.9, category, submenu, labels, selection

I need to create New Label Icon for selected categories, How can I create new labels icons  like,

[image]

Comment: create a category custom attribute, If category set that attribute in backend then label will show.

Comment: could you pls explain briefly

Comment: Below answer is right you have to go through with that.

Comment: @Ramsipl : could you pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50817/new-category-label

Comment: Not working....

Comment: are you using infortis ultimo theme ??

Comment: Nope, am using https://www.templatemonster.com/fitness-magento-free-theme.html#gref

Comment: @JeevaRathinam you just need to create one yes/no attribute for category in backend and add condition of that attribute before displaying that category name at frontend.

Comment: @Nits : How can i create yes/no attribute for category in backend

Comment: @JeevaRathinam check below URL
https://gist.github.com/aleron75/7304592
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/add-a-extra-category-attribute-under-general-infomation-tab
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/add-category-custom-attribute-with-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom category attribute (Yes or no), You can get help here :

https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11408/21339

Set the value of those category (yes/no) from backed and then within your template put you logic.

**Edit**

Here is the code for this, I have not tested this code, Please do it on demo site.

Step 1 : Add the following code in your app/etc/Arunendra_Pratap.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
      <Arunendra_Pratap>
         <active>true</active>
         <codePool>local</codePool>
      </Arunendra_Pratap>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2 :Add the following code to the app/code/local/Arunendra/Pratap/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arunendra_Pratap>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Arunendra_Pratap>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Arunendra_Pratap</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step 3 :Add the custom attribute to the app/code/local/Arunendra/Pratap/sql/add_category_attribute/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php file as shown below.

```
  <?php
    $this->startSetup();
    $this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'is_new_cat', array(
        'group'         => 'General Information',
        'input'         => 'select',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => 'Is new',
        'backend'       => '',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    ));

    $this->endSetup();
```

**Edit :**

You need to modify this file /app/code/community/WP/CustomMenu/Block and

find this  public function drawCustomMenuItem and replace with this

```
 public function drawCustomMenuItem($category, $level = 0, $last = false)
    {
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) return;
        $htmlTop = array();
        $id = $category->getId();
        $isNew = $category->getIsNewCat()== 1 ? 'new-cat-class' : '';
        // --- Static Block ---
        $blockId = sprintf(self::CUSTOM_BLOCK_TEMPLATE, $id); // --- static block key
        #Mage::log($blockId);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array(array('like' => $blockId . '_w%'), array('eq' => $blockId)))
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $blockId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getIdentifier();
        #Mage::log($blockId);
        $blockHtml = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($blockId)->toHtml();
        // --- Sub Categories ---
        $activeChildren = $this->_getActiveChildren($category, $level);
        // --- class for active category ---
        $active = ''; if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) $active = ' act';
        // --- Popup functions for show ---
        $drawPopup = ($blockHtml || count($activeChildren));
        if ($drawPopup) {
            $htmlTop[] = '<div id="menu' . $id . '" class="menu' . $active . '" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\');" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')">';
        } else {
            $htmlTop[] = '<div id="menu' . $id . '" class="menu' . $active . '">';
        }
        // --- Top Menu Item ---
        $htmlTop[] = '<div class="parentMenu">';
        if ($level == 0 && $drawPopup) {
            $htmlTop[] = '<a  class="level' . $level . $active .$isNew. '" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'">';
        } else {
            $htmlTop[] = '<a  class="level' . $level . $active . .$isNew.'" href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'">';
        }
        $name = $this->escapeHtml($category->getName());
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/non_breaking_space')) {
            $name = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $name);
        }
        $htmlTop[] = '<span>' . $name . '</span>';
        $htmlTop[] = '</a>';
        $htmlTop[] = '</div>';
        $htmlTop[] = '</div>';
        $this->_topMenu[] = implode("\n", $htmlTop);
        // --- Add Popup block (hidden) ---
        if ($drawPopup) {
            $htmlPopup = array();
            // --- Popup function for hide ---
            $htmlPopup[] = '<div id="popup' . $id . '" class="wp-custom-menu-popup" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')" onmouseover="wpPopupOver(this, event, \'popup' . $id . '\', \'menu' . $id . '\')">';
            // --- draw Sub Categories ---
            if (count($activeChildren)) {
                $columns = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/columns/count');
                $htmlPopup[] = '<div class="block1">';
                $htmlPopup[] = $this->drawColumns($activeChildren, $columns);
                $htmlPopup[] = '<div class="clearBoth"></div>';
                $htmlPopup[] = '</div>';
            }
            // --- draw Custom User Block ---
            if ($blockHtml) {
                $htmlPopup[] = '<div id="' . $blockId . '" class="block2">';
                $htmlPopup[] = $blockHtml;
                $htmlPopup[] = '</div>';
            }
            $htmlPopup[] = '</div>';
            $this->_popupMenu[] = implode("\n", $htmlPopup);
        }
    }
```

and add this style

```
.new-cat-class{ color:red !important;}
```

**Note:** if this work revert back the changes and override this block with local module.
http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @ arunendra : where i can below code,

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/txyORnW.png

Comment: @JeevaRathinam just read above the pink line "script must be located in the folder with the same name (in our case path will be ‘app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/sql/add_category_attribute’) "

Comment: could u pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50817/new-category-label

Comment: @ arunendra : my sqlversion : http://i.imgur.com/B0gG9BU.png

Comment: and my code http://i.imgur.com/wHFjAIT.png

Comment: not working.......

Comment: Where i can improve my fault

Comment: @JeevaRathinam please see my updated ans

Comment: not working........

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6a9jgdW.png

Comment: I have checked same code in my local magento 1.9.2.4 and it's working fine.Please flush your magento cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50824/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-arunendra).

Comment: @ arunendra : could you share screenshots, may I see the new label on category

Comment: @ Arunendra: After completion of what you told, Finally I get (is new) on the backend, after click new, there are no changes on the front end, help me.

Comment: Not working ............

Comment: Please share the code  where you have written for get the menu ?

Comment: Am using the extension, https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html

Comment: @JeevaRathinam I have updated the answer please check