# How add (new) label along with name in Magento categories menu

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Can somebody suggest how to add (new) label along with
category/subcategory menu name like shown in the picture given.

Is there any Extension for this? If somebody has done this please help.

[image]

Comment: which version of magento you are using ?

Comment: @Manoj Deswal  -->Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

Comment: have you checked this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152100/how-can-set-new-label-icon-for-selected-category-in-menu-popup

Comment: yes i have checked but none worked

Comment: try adding new attribute , http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/

Comment: added new attribute it shows on admin category but does show on frontend

Comment: might be need some css tweaks , inspect element ...and check it appears in code or not

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned Magento version, I have listed out few extensions for both versions. Please have a look at these links:

**For Magento 1.x:**

https://www.magestore.com/magento-mega-menu-extension.html

https://www.rootways.com/shop/magento-mega-menu-extension

https://cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/magento-mega-menu-extension

**For Magento 2.x:**

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-mega-menu-extension.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/ubertheme-module-ubmegamenu.html

https://www.rootways.com/shop/magento-2-mega-menu-extension